# SugarCrm Synchronization with other applications

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to SugarCRM, i have created SugarCRM's web to lead form on my website which is having four fields i.e. frist name, last name, address and phone . On submit this info get updated in SugarCRM in Leadlist. Now the requirement is whenever any update happens on SugarCRM, I have to update other data source, in this case marklogic. I want to keep same data on sugar and marklogic.

Whenever any update triggers the SugarCRM it should send some webservice or other method with updated information to marklogic, so that marklogic data should be in sync.

How can I do that?  Any suggestion would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new REST interface in MarkLogic 6, specifically the CRUD APIs. Using these you should be able to pretty easily make webservice updates to the database without writing any xQuery.

http://developer.marklogic.com/try/rest/index